# radiogroup not working in meteor template

Tags: javascript, meteor

This Meteor code is expected to show the data supplied by the helper but it is now showing any.  What is wrong and how to fix it?

```js
<template name="options">
  <radiogroup>
    {{#each values}}
      <radio value="{{this.result}}" label="{{this.label}}"></radio>
    {{/each}}
  </radiogroup>
</template>
```

**edit**
The data can be shown if I change the code to:

```js
<template name="options">
  <div class="twin-group js-radioGroup" data-id={{_id}}>
    <ul class="upShift">
      {{#each values}}
        <li>
          <label class="twin-item">
            <input type="radio" value={{this.result}}>
            <span class="radio-label">{{this.label}}</span>
          </label>
        </li>
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: what have you tried so far? have you gotten the data showing up w/o the radio group and proceeded from there? from where do the radiogroup and radio element come?

Comment: @zim please see the edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not see you define the `radiogroup` template so I suppose you use it as a html tag. The thing is there is no `radiogroup` tag in HTML, that is why you code does not work.